# convert file into grayscale image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to convert files (any file as exe, apk) to a gray scale image. I have prepared the binary bits of the file using the code below. However, I am stuck in grouping 8-bits to represent a pixel in my image, so each pixel is from 0-255.  The literatire showed that Malware can be classified by converting it to a gray scale image and apply CNN model for classification

```
import cv2
import numpy
import os
import binascii

filePath = "240387329dee4f03f98a89a2feff9bf30dcba61fcf614cdac24129da54442762"
file = open(filePath, "rb")
with file:
    byte = file.read()
    hexadecimal = binascii.hexlify(byte)
    decimal = int(hexadecimal, 16)
    binary = bin(decimal)[2:].zfill(8)
    print("hex: %s, decimal: %s, binary: %s" % (hexadecimal, decimal, binary))
```

Edit:

I have written the below, where I fixed the width of the image. Any feedback?

```
import cv2
import numpy
import os
import binascii
import array
import scipy.misc
#print (format(5,"b"))

filename='240387329dee4f03f98a89a2feff9bf30dcba61fcf614cdac24129da54442762';
f=open(filename,'rb');
ln = os.path.getsize(filename);
width = 500;
rem = ln%width;
a=array.array("B");
a.fromfile(f,ln-rem);
f.close;
g=numpy.reshape(a,(len(a)/width,width));
g= numpy.uint8(g);
scipy.misc.imsave('Malware.png',g);
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain a little better. It's not actually normal to convert executable files into images.

Comment: You want to take a screenshot from your app and check if that is a malware app or not?

Comment: I'm having a hard time imagining this. Say your executable is 1,000 bytes long, that's going to make very different looking images if I make them 20x50 pixels, 50x20 pixels, 100x10 pixels or 1000x1 pixels so how is your CNN going to have any hope?

Comment: Yes. By converting the file into a gray scale image, it could be classified as Malicious or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to convert the data to hexadecimal or binary, all you need to do is converting the binary data (bytes sequence) to 2D array.

The problem is that not any 1D array can be reshaped into 2D array.
In case number of bytes is a prime number = N, for example, you will get a 1xN image (an ugly single row or column image).

The following example assumes the image dimensions must be square, and uses padding to complete the number of bytes as required:

```
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt, ceil
import cv2

#Input file name (random file I found in my folder).
input_file_name = 'test_cython.cp36-win_amd64.pyd';

#Read the whole file to data
with open(input_file_name, 'rb') as binary_file:        
    data = binary_file.read()

# Data length in bytes
data_len = len(data)

# d is a verctor of data_len bytes
d = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.uint8)

# Assume image shape should be close to square
sqrt_len = int(ceil(sqrt(data_len)))  # Compute square toot and round up

# Requiered length in bytes.
new_len = sqrt_len*sqrt_len

# Number of bytes to pad (need to add zeros to the end of d)
pad_len = new_len - data_len

# Pad d with zeros at the end.
# padded_d = np.pad(d, (0, pad_len))
padded_d = np.hstack((d, np.zeros(pad_len, np.uint8)))

# Reshape 1D array into 2D array with sqrt_len pad_len x sqrt_len (im is going to be a Grayscale image).
im = np.reshape(padded_d, (sqrt_len, sqrt_len))

# Save image
cv2.imwrite('im.png', im)

# Display image
cv2.imshow('im' ,im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:
[image]

---

Building an image that can be used for restoring original file:

In case you want to get the image, and restore the original file (byte equal, without padding), you need to restore the original data length in the image.
(You may also restore the length of the padding).

The following implementation, stores the original data length in the first 8 pixels.

After reading the image, the padding and stored length can be removed, and original file can be restored.

Here is an "encoding" and "decoding" example:

```
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt, ceil
import cv2
import struct

#Input file name
input_file_name = 'test_cython.cp36-win_amd64.pyd';

#Read the whole file to data
with open(input_file_name, 'rb') as binary_file:        
    data = binary_file.read()

# Data length in bytes
data_len = len(data)

# d is a verctor of data_len bytes
d = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.uint8)

data_len_as_bytes = np.frombuffer(struct.pack("Q", data_len), dtype=np.uint8) # Convert data_len to 8 bytes

data_len = data_len + len(data_len_as_bytes) #Update length to include the 8 bytes

# Set data_len as first 8 bytes of d
d = np.hstack((data_len_as_bytes, d))

# Assume image shape should be close to square
sqrt_len = int(ceil(sqrt(data_len)))  # Compute square toot and round up

# Requiered length in bytes.
new_len = sqrt_len*sqrt_len

# Number of bytes to pad (need to add zeros to the end of d)
pad_len = new_len - data_len

# Pad d with zeros at the end.
# padded_d = np.pad(d, (0, pad_len))
padded_d = np.hstack((d, np.zeros(pad_len, np.uint8)))

# Reshape 1D array into 2D array with sqrt_len pad_len x sqrt_len (im is going to be a Grayscale image).
im = np.reshape(padded_d, (sqrt_len, sqrt_len))

# Save image
cv2.imwrite('im.png', im)

# Display image
#cv2.imshow('im' ,im)
#cv2.waitKey(0)
#cv2.destroyAllWindows()


# Restore original data:
##################################
input_file_name = 'test.bin';  #Output file name

im = cv2.imread('im.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Convert 2D to 1D
padded_d = im.flatten()

# Get original length
data_len_as_bytes = padded_d[0:8]

orig_data_len = struct.unpack("Q", data_len_as_bytes.tobytes())

# Crop the original data bytes (without the padding).
data = padded_d[8:8+orig_data_len[0]]

#Write d whole file to binary file
with open(input_file_name, 'wb') as binary_file:
    binary_file.write(data)
```

Now you can upload any (small) file to Stack Overflow as an image, and let someone else restoring your file.

Comment: Thanks for the great effort! I got the following error TypeError: pad() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: I replaced `padded_d = np.pad(d, (0, pad_len))` with `padded_d = np.hstack((d, np.zeros(pad_len, np.uint8)))`.